# Convert Shapefile to CSV using FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a simple shapefile (point) that has only ID in the attribute table. I can transform shp to csv but this only gets the ID into the CSV file.

What transformer/settings do I need to read the x,y coordinates of each point in the shapefile and pass them to the CSV writer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [CoordinateExtractor](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/coordinateextractor.htm) transformer.  According to the documentation:

> Retrieves the value of the x, y, and z coordinate at the specified
>   index into attributes.  A negative index can be used to indicate the
>   position relative to the end of the feature (-1 is the last
>   coordinate, -2 the second last, and so on).  The index can be entered
>   as an integer, or may be taken from the value of another attribute by
>   selecting the attribute name from the pull-down list. If the index is
>   invalid, then the translation will be terminated.
>
> If the feature was two-dimensional, then the Z attribute will be given
>   the default value specified.
>
> If the feature was a multi-part feature (aggregate), each part’s
>   coordinates are indexed sequentially.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks. I knew I had forgotten some trivial things after being away from the program a while!